# Reading csv files with messy structure with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, import-from-csv

I am having trouble reading in a csv file.  The problem is due to the structure of the file.  I want to read it into a pandas dataframe object but some lines have more columns then others.  For example I might expect most of the data to be in a form like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3   
a,b,c,   
a,b,c,   
a,a,b,c,   
a,b,c,c,   
a,b,c
```

Is there a way I can read in the csv file by line so that it will create two data frames, one with the expected number of columns and another one with the rows needed further examination?

Comment: DataFrames are inherently tabular in nature.  There is no such thing as a DataFrame where different rows have different numbers of columns.  What do you ultimately intend to do with the rows that have too many values?

Comment: i will need to look and see what values were duplicated and remove them.  each row should have 40 columns but some values are duplicated and thus the rows are shifted over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way -- inefficient, but effective -- is to make more space than you'll need:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("knop.csv", names=range(6))
>>> df
      0     1     2    3   4   5
0  Col1  Col2  Col3  NaN NaN NaN
1     a     b     c  NaN NaN NaN
2     a     b     c  NaN NaN NaN
3     a     a     b    c NaN NaN
4     a     b     c    c NaN NaN
5     a     b     c  NaN NaN NaN
>>> df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
>>> df
      0     1     2    3
0  Col1  Col2  Col3  NaN
1     a     b     c  NaN
2     a     b     c  NaN
3     a     a     b    c
4     a     b     c    c
5     a     b     c  NaN
```

After the data's all in a frame, processing and separating it (including promoting the first row back to column names) should be straightforward.

Comment: thank you. this is the method i have started to move forward with.

Comment: @DSM Apparently this is not a Pandas approved way to read in the file. It may work, it may fail spectacularly. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23509#issuecomment-435918889

Answer (score 0):

You should probably treat this as a two-phase process: data cleaning, then loading.  The cleaning step you can do with Python's built-in `csv` module, inspecting each line one-by-one.  You'll need something like this to handle your jagged lines, unless you simply want to discard the extra columns.